# maintain mock data in JavaScript unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, karma-runner

i'm looking for a nice and best practice way to maintain my mocked objects in JavaScript unit tests.

My first concern is that a unit test would be focused on the functionality, such that the `describe` and `it` would be shorter and so it would not contain the mocked object within them.

bad example:

```js
it('some testing example', function() {
    const currentProduct = {
        name: 'VSp',
        description: 'dfdf',
        id: 'D4774719D085414E9D5642D1ACD59D20',
        version: '0.10',
        status: 'READY'
    };


    const obj = {
        product: {
            productEditor: {
                data: currentProduct
            },
            productComponents: {
                componentEditor: {
                    qdata: {},
                    qschema: {},
                    data: {}
                },
                network: {
                    nicEditor: {},
                    nicList: []
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const results = exampleFunctionUnderTest(obj);
    expect(results.qdata).toExist();
    expect(results.qschema).toExist();
    expect(results.componentData).toExist();
});
```

As you can realize, the mocked objects may be much bigger and it makes the unit test code very ugly, unclear, unreadable...

This unti test is much easier to read and understand:

```js
it('some testing example', function() {

    const results = exampleFunctionUnderTest(someMockedObjectFromXXX);
    expect(results.qdata).toExist();
    expect(results.qschema).toExist();
    expect(results.componentData).toExist();
});
```

The naive solution is, obviously, to have them on separate `.json` or `.js` files. But then I might have a huge `.json` files all around the `*.test.js` files that might cause some "noisy" working environment. <- this is my second concern - how to maintain those files properly.

I didn't succeed in finding the right post to make clear stuff in this topic, I'll be happy to get some references to recommended posts, or if you have your own experience to share, of what you've done in your projects.

In case it matters, I'm using `karma` and `mocha` as my testing frameworks

Cheers!

Comment: Just to add something that could be helpful there are some libraries to mock things: like sinon.js, or if you need to mock ajax: mockjx or amplifyJS. For json there is mockJson.

Comment: @vitomd can you refer me to an open-source project so I could see some files arrangement example?

Comment: no that I could think, but maybe you need a factory to build objects like FactoryGirl for Rails. It´s seems that there are a couple for Javascript (I did´t use them) https://github.com/Coffa/factory_girl and https://github.com/rosiejs/rosie So your test objects are organized in the Factory

Comment: ok... you're right... using a Factory in addition to frameworks you've mentioned above. I'll play with it a bit